# banner - horizontal text

Tags: macos, command-line

On my Linux box, if I do `banner message` I get a horizontal banner saying "message".

However, on my Mac I get a **vertical** banner. How do you revert this to horizontal?

Answer (score 16):

The default `banner` on macOS does not have any option to change orientation.

However, `figlet` is available in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

> brew install figlet

Answer (score -3):

Since it's a banner, by default prints vertically, in larger characters, visible from afar in landscape page setup, without having to setup printer to print in landscape. You may change the size of print with "-w" flag.

Orientation may be changed with a text editor or in printer page setup before printing.

If you wanted to display banner horizontally on monitor, then you may rotate the monitor display either physically, or via display properties described here:

https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/589248-screen-rotation-option-is-not-available-on-mac-os